# Prevent access of sub-/addondomain via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains: `main.com` and `addon.net`

On my shared hosting account I create an addon-domain for`addon.net` which automatically creates a folder in the main-domain's directory as well as a subdomain.

I want to change the accessability of the addon domain via the maindomain:

```
http://addon.main.com
http://main.com/addon.net/
```

Now both serve the index.html from `addon.net`

Both URLs should result in a `"404 - not found"` error.

What I have right now on `main.com/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addon.net/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [L]
```

And in `addon.net/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.main.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main.com/ [R=301,L]
```

And now everything redirects to `main.com`:

`http://main.com/addon.net/` redirects to `http://www.main.com`

`http://addon.main.com` redirects to `http://www.main.com`

`http://addon.net` redirects to `http://www.main.com`

My question: which rules should I add to which .htaccess-file in order to get the desired results:

`addon.main.com` redirecting to `main.com/404.html`

`main.com/addon.net` redirecting to `main.com/404.html`

`addon.net` serving `addon.net/index.html`

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect access from anything except addon.net (and redirect the other requests to a 404 page), all you need to do is use these lines in the `.htaccess` file inside `addon.net` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?addon\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule - /404.html [L]
```

Comment: that doesn't work, the .htaccess on my main domain is now empty except 1 line (DirectoryIndex index.html index.php parking-page.html) which is added automatically and the .htaccess in addon.net has your 3 lines, unfortunately I get the exact same results as before

Comment: did you remove all other lines in  `addon.net/.htaccess` ?

Comment: @oussame: yes, i removed all previous lines in addon.net/.htaccess